# Limit/offset on a joined table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm implementing a GraphQL API, using SQLAlchemy. The problem I'm facing now is that I want to be able to apply a limit and offset to related entities of the main entity.

In SQL terms, I want to apply limit and offset to the joined table. For example I join User with all Addresses, but with a limit of 2, so no more than 2 of the users addresses are loaded.

Note that I'm currently handling joins in the following way, in order to filter on the relations:

```
query = session.query(User).\
    filter(SOME FILTER ON USER PROPERTY).\
    limit(5).from_self().\  # optional limit on the amount of users
    outerjoin(User.addresses).\
    options(contains_eager(User.addresses)).\
    filter(SOME FILTER ON ADDRESS)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still looking for an answer :)

Comment: I guess the first solution here is what you're looking for:

https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/4-ways-to-join-only-the-first-row-in-sql